# wpf scale canvas width based on children

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a `Canvas` inside a `Grid`, on a `columndefinition` of Width `Auto`. The Canvas does not automatically enlarge to hold it's elements. It's width always stays `zero`. I have to manually hardcode a width.

```
<Grid Height="35"
      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
      MouseEnter="floater_MouseEnter"
      MouseLeave="floater_MouseLeave"
      >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Canvas Grid.Column="1"
            Background="White"
            Height="32.7"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Visibility="Visible"
            >
        <TextBlock Text="asdfsdf" FontSize="23"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I want the canvas's width to scale based on the elements. What should I do?

Comment: This is what can be expected when choosing Canvas instead of Grid. Canvas is used for absolute positioning, and it does not grow or shrink with its children. The simple fix is replacing it with a Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas` won't work in that way. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Canvas is the only panel element that has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has default Height and Width properties of
>   zero, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes
>   its child elements. Child elements of a Canvas are never resized, they
>   are just positioned at their designated coordinates. This provides
>   flexibility for situations in which inherent sizing constraints or
>   alignment are not needed or wanted. For cases in which you want child
>   content to be automatically resized and aligned, it is usually best to
>   use a Grid element.

If you still want to use `Canvas` for some reason. You can bind to the `Width` of the `TextBox`. Like,

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Background="Green" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=text}">
        <TextBlock Text="asdfsdf" FontSize="23" x:Name="text"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```